# Understanding the working of process pool in an infinite loop

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

In the following snippet, as I understand, a pool of two processes is being created and then the main script enters an infinite loop while continuously checking for messages and delegates the task to some function `action_fn` if it finds any message.

```
p = Pool(processes = 2)

while True:
  message = receive_message_from_queue()
  if message is not None:
      # Do some task
      p.map_async(action_fn, [temp_iterables])
```

What would happen here if there are 100 messages in the queue? Will there be 100 processes created by python? Or is it that at any time only two messages will be processed? Also, in the case such as this, what is the way to kill the process when its task is done and recreate the process when there is a new message?

Answer (score 1):

The [Pool of Workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) is a design pattern which aims to separate the service logic from the business logic.

With service logic is intended all the logic needed to support a given task such as data storage and retrieval, metrics, logging and error handling.

Business logic instead refers to the components which do the "actual job" such as enriching or transforming the data, generating statistics etc.

It is usually implemented adopting the [Publisher/Subscriber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) design pattern where one or more workers listen to a queue of jobs which is fed from the service side.

Most of the Pool implementations require the User to set a static number of workers during their declaration. Some more advanced ones allow to change the number of workers dynamically.

Jobs can be scheduled in non-blocking (asynchronous) fashion allowing the service to continue its execution flow or in blocking (synchronous) mode stopping the execution until results are not ready.

In your specific example, you are declaring a Pool with 2 workers. Assuming you are using the `multiprocessing.Pool` class, the interpreter will start 2 processes which will wait for new jobs. When you call `map_async`, the iterable gets split into multiple chunks which get enqueued inside the Pool internal queue. The workers will pick the chunks in the order they arrive, run the `action_fn` function against them and publish the results in a second results queue which gets consumed by the service.

Multiple calls to `map_async` result in more chucks getting appended to the internal queue. Virtually the queue is infinite in size. Practically, if you manage to fill it up, the subsequent call to `map_async` would block until the workers make some more space for new jobs to be enqueued.

You don't need to "kill the process when is done" as the Pool manages the workflow for you in a transparent manner. Concretely, the process never dies. It simply picks the next task from the queue and executes it until there are no more tasks available. At that point it goes into sleep until either new tasks are not scheduled or the Pool itself is terminated.

Comment: <<Jobs ... stopping the execution until results are ?not? ready.>> I guess you mean <<... until results are ready.>>